# Suspending a non-looping thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread A acting as a GUI or CLI that spawns another thread B. Thread B has its run method like below

```
public void run() {
    doSomething(); //Might take 30 seconds
    crazyCalculation(); //Might take 30-60 minutes
    doTheLastThingBeforeExit(); //Might take another 30 seconds
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to pause the execution of thread B from thread A (to externally (having user looking at the log) analyze the current result) then resume thread B whenever user finishes his analysis? Is this achievable without modifying thread B's contents? (Some other way to achieve what the deprecated Thread.suspend() method does)

If thread B's content has to be modified (I suppose with wait() and notify()), where should they be in thread B? Should I modify crazyCalculation() to have multiple stage and have my run method be

```
public void run() {
    doSomething();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStage; i++) {
        crazyCalculationAtStage(i); //Broken down to smaller chunk 1 minute each stage
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isLocked()) {
                 myLock.wait();
            }
        }
    }
    doTheLastThingBeforeExit();
}
```

Comment: *"where should they be in thread B"* Where every, logically, it makes sense to pause the thread

Comment: A thread can only be paused with its cooperation. Otherwise, you might pause it while it's holding a critical lock that the thread that pauses it needs to acquire and then *boom*, you deadlock.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html. It also explains how to implement something similar to `suspend()` and `resume()` without using the deprecated methods.

Comment: Possible? yes.  (See comment by isnot2bad, above)  Good idea?  Generally speaking, no.  `t.suspend()` is deprecated because it's a great way to put deadlock bugs in your software.  Does your background thread lock any locks?  What would happen if the background thread was holding one or more locks at the moment when the UI thread suspended it?  Is there any possibility that the foreground thread would try to acquire one of those same locks?  If so, then there's your deadlock.  It's never a wise idea to have one thread _force_ another to do anything.  Threads should always cooperate.